# Apple TV wireless debugging Unable to connect

Tags: xcode, xcode9, apple-tv

I am trying to pair my apple TV (4th Gen) running tvOS 11.1 with Xcode 9. After entering the pairing code, Xcode tries to setup the Apple TV for wireless debugging and enabling development mode, but fails with the error
**"An error was encountered while attempting to communicate with this device. (End of file.)"** See below image

**Note** that I was able to pair with my apple TV successfully and run an app on it couple of weeks ago using Xcode 9 wireless debugging feature. **Wireless debugging works fine for iphone and iPad.** Now, I seem to be having problem with my Apple TV.

**UPDATE:** Now I have tried even resetting my AppleTV, still same issue.

Xcode 9 Devices and Simulators Window

[image]

I have tried restarting my apple TV and tried reconnecting it with Xcode multiple times, but I get the same error always.
Do I need to reset my apple TV or is there any other work around available to fix this issue ?

Comment: The same story. XCode 10. Yesterday it worked perfectly, today I ran into same bug :-(

Comment: See if one of them are on beta. I would recommend checking Apple TV if you have switched on Get Beta Updates on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, I had to use Xcode beta version, as I was installing app on the  beta tvOS version. I didn't notice that Apple TV was updated to tvOS 11.1 which is in beta at the moment.

**Solution:** Using Xcode 9.1 (beta) to install the app on Apple TV 4 worked perfectly.

Comment: For me Apple TV (4th gen) does not appear in the devices list at all, in Xcode. Using Xcode 9.2, and a brand new Apple TV 4th gen, version tvOS 11.x

Comment: It fixed itself after restarting the Apple TV.

Comment: BTW I am using these devices at work; the work WIFI is kind of crappy with lots of limitations. I had to do pairing over a tethered iPhone. But it worked, after restarting the Apple TV once.